# How do I sort while still keeping the same array indices?

Tags: php, mysql, database

The index is automatic, the indexes are 0, 1, 2, etc. nothing special.

But the key to the database is auto-incremented. meaning the index directly correlates to the key of the database. So after the sort, I can do a query and retrieve the info on that row with that key.

But I think that once you `sort()`, it changes the index, therefore I would lose that correlation between the index and the key of the database therefore making the array quite useless...so my question is how do I keep that correlation while still sorting so that the highest value goes to the top?

And then after that's successful, how do I sort through an array like that?

Thanks so much for your help and patience,
Binny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is [`asort()`](http://php.net/asort) or [`arsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php).  According to the documentation for `asort()`,

> This function sorts an array such that
>   array indices maintain their
>   correlation with the array elements
>   they are associated with. This is used
>   mainly when sorting associative arrays
>   where the actual element order is
>   significant.

`arsort()` sorts in the reverse direction.

Comment: how does that work?;

" Sort an array and maintain index association ";

that sounds perfect, i guess ill read up on this. thanks =)

Comment: Did you click on the link? It sorts an array and maintains index association.

Answer (score 0):

Use `asort`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php